# Gets firebase emulator updates on a another project

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am running emulator on app a with the following command :

```
firebase emulators:start --import=./emulator-data --only=auth,firestore,functions,storage,pubsub",
```

from APP B im just connecting to the emu by adding the
`FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=8080`

the issue is when I am going directly to the emu i will get only the based data that saved to the file

I wont get the new collection or new entry if i will try to add or even if i will restart the second app .
i will always get the original data and only the original data

how can it be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

Found that the gcloud project id was different than the emulator project id

`gcloud config set project ${Project ID}`

saved my day